# Can you Load Plugins inline in Chartjs 4?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been trying to use Chart JS 4 and its custom plugin API. I can register my plugin globally but not inline.

---

According to the [Chart JS 4 docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) you can add plugins globally, using registration while other plugins can be used inline because they do not require registration.

> WARNING
>
> inline plugins are not registered. Some plugins require registering,
> i.e. can't be used inline.

This sounds vague, and I couldn't find any good information on what that means. In Chart JS 2.x.x I could add a plugin inline but I needed some more features so I had to update to version 4. If I cannot add a plugin inline I guess I will just have to make sure that I turn the plugin off on charts that don't require it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

The solution seemed the be that I had a typo somewhere in my code when comparing it to [this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/plugins/quadrants.html) sample as pointed out by the helpful comments below. I honestly do not know which part of my code had a typo I just know that it had to because when I used the sample code and worked from there everything worked perfectly.

Comment: In CHART:JS 4 you can add inline plugins like in previous versions. Of course, they are working only for that chart instance. The warning means that if you need to implement registration hooks (before/afterRegistration) you cannot use an inline plugin

Comment: sample: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/plugins/quadrants.html

Comment: Hmm that is odd because I am not using before or afterRegistration I am just using afterDraw and not getting anything to work, even a basic `console.log` statement.

Comment: can you provide a sample?

Comment: I was able to get the official example from chartjs to work. I am going to reverse engineer it to my specifications and see if I can get something working